# Align Text with the content of a TextField

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, alignment, desktop-application

Is there a way to automatically align a `Text` with the contents of a `TextField`? I wouldn't like to hardcode the padding if it's avoidable.

The `Text` should display an error message if the value in the `TextField` doesn't match its rules.

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun Demo() {
    Dialog(onDismissRequest = {}) {
        MaterialTheme {
            Card(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp, 5.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp),
                elevation = 8.dp
            ) {
                Column(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(3.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(5.dp)
                ) {
                    TextField(
                        label = { Text("Hallo Text!") },
                        value = "",
                        onValueChange = { },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    Text("Hallo below!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using Jetpack Compose with Material Design 3, you can use the `supportingText` parameter of the [`TextField`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldColors)):

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    label = { Text("Enter Text") },
    supportingText = { 
        Text(
            text = "Hello below!", 
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
        ) 
    }
)
```

This will result in an error message that is aligned to the start of the `TextField`:
[image: Sample Image]

If you are using Compose Multiplatform, check out [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/discussions/2518) to find out how to use Material3 components. With regular Compose, you need the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-alpha02'
```